# How to uninstall jprofiler, ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, jprofiler

Need help uninstalling jjrofiler. Didn't realize it needed a license. Installed via .sh executable.

Comment: Just run the `uninstall` in the installation directory or simply delete the installation directory

Answer (score 4):

if you goto your jProfiler installation directory you will find the executable called uninstall, just run that from the terminal.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run the `./uninstall` from jprofiler installation directory.

```
#cd /home/jprofiler12
#./uninstall
```

Comment: A bit of description is required to know if this has to be written in a script or something.